# Queries on 3d Points

Tags: algorithm, optimization, 3d

I have an array of 3d points. Each point has an x,y and z coordinate. The maximum size of the array can be 777777. I have Q queries each providing me with four numbers A, B, C, D. for each query I have to output the following sum.

[image]

```
Q <=77
1 <= A, B, C <=77
1 <= Xi, Yi, Zi <=77
1 <= Di <= 777
N <= 777777
```

What I have done: For each query calculate the given sum using two nested loops giving me a complexity of O(Q*N^2). Is there a better way to calculate it ?

Edit:
What I know for sure is this is not a geometric problem. The maximum value of xi-xj is 76 and min is -76. This applies to yi and zi too. so total possible combinations are 153*153*153. Now in a query we have to count how many times a particular combination occurs in the array and solve the sum for that combination only once. The problem reduces to finding how many times a particular combination of ( xi-xj , yi-yj, zi-zj). Can someone take it ahead from here? I suspect we can use fast Fourier transform here. I have seen them getting used in these kind of problems before. But I have no clue how to start

Comment: If you're not getting answers here, try math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is there really fourth powers? If they were second powers, it would have geometric sense.

Comment: @stgatilov Yes they are actually fourth powers.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a mistake, because it neglects the absolute value function. I don't see a way to get past this.

You can rewrite the query as A * SUM_i!=j (Xi-Xj)/sqrt(...) + B * SUM_i!=j(Yi-Yj)/sqrt(...) + ...

Once you have done this you can see that if you have calculated the values for A=1, B=C=D=0, and B=1,A=C=D=0 and C=1,A=B=D=0 and D=1, A=B=C=0 as e.g. Qa, Qb, Qc, Qd, then you can find the values for any other values of A, B, C, and D as A * Qa + B * Qb + C * Qc + D * Qd.

This takes the complexity down to O(N^2)

Comment: There is an absolute value in the sum. `|a + b| != |a| + |b|`, so I don't think you can do this.

Comment: @IVlad you are right. This is definitely not the right solution

Comment: Yes you are right - I have modified my answer to show that it is incorrect, but left it as a cautionary tale.